# Android get json from url response null and error from localhost

Tags: php, android, json

I have an android java source code :

```
private void getDataFromServer(String url){
        InputStream is = null;
        JSONObject json = null;
        String output = "";
        URL _url;
        URLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {
            _url = new URL(url);
            urlConnection = _url.openConnection();
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error due to a malformed URL " + e.toString());

        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "IO error " + e.toString());

        }

        try {
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
            is = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder(is.available());
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line).append('\n');
            }
            output = total.toString();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "IO error " + e.toString());

        }
//        finally{
//            urlConnection.disconnect();
//        }

        try {
            json = new JSONObject(output);
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
    }
```

and the URL = http://localhost/API/getdata.php
will return :

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "nama_kab": "KAB. BOGOR",
        "jml_miskin": "479",
        "presentase_miskin": "8.91",
        "indeks_kedalaman": "1.27",
        "indeks_keparahan": "0.29",
        "garis_kemiskinan": "280312",
        "latitude": "-6.59504",
        "longitude": "106.817"
    }
]
```

i use debugging and breakpoint, it always stop and error when :
`is = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());`
i tried add charset and any other stackoverflow suggest, but still error.
please help me

this is my manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: You have a lot of catch blocks. Which is good. But the normal e.printStackTrace(); is missing. Put it in everywhere. Further you should not continue if there is a catch but return directly with an error string. At the moment you do not know what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first, the response is not an object (`JSONObject`), but an array, so you should do your parsing accordingly (use `JSONArray`). Second, `Content-Type` is a header sent by the server, clients use the `Accept` header to indicate what kind of data they expect.

Comment: I tried it, what you suggest. but still application terminated after execute `is = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());`

Comment: stackTrace = {StackTraceElement[0]831872922800}

Comment: but your stack trace isn't what we usually expect when we talk about it. it is a list of methods executed until the point the exception was thrown. put e.printStacktrace() in your catch block, its output is most useful